# How can i take the name of a directory from the user and then create it using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a file explorer app in node.js. In this app users can view, upload, create, and delete their files/directories. I know how to create new directories using node.js but **I don't know how to take the name of this new directory from the user and then create the directory using that name**. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Below is the code for the creation of a new directory.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const newFolder = (FullStaticPath, FolderName) => {
    const FullStaticPathCleaned = FullStaticPath.replace(/\s/g,'\ ');
    const commandOutput = execSync(`cd "${itemFullStaticPathCleaned}"`);
    console.log(commandOutput);  
    try{
        fs.mkdirSync(FolderName);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(`mkdirSync error: ${err}\nDirectory was not created`);
    }
};
```

The Html Portion is below

```
...
<div class="modal fade" id="newfolder">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add new folder</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Folder Name...">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
...
```

How can I get the name of the folder from the HTML portion and then create the directory using that name??.

Can someone help me?

Comment: you need to set up `createServer` with http `POST` method to get data from html (or client). Check out express router which makes things easier

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar I used this condition `if(request.method === 'POST'){
code goes here }` and it is working, but now the page is not giving any response back it just keep on loading. Also, I want this application purely on node not on any of its framework.